# Show that the difference of two sequences of straight lines converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Define $d_{\varepsilon,a}(x) = \frac{f(a+\varepsilon)-f(a)}{\varepsilon}(x-a)+f(a)$ $\quad \forall(x,a,\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^*$ where $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. That is $(a_n),(b_n),(c_n) \in (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\to + \infty} (a_n,b_n,c_n) = (0,0,0)$.

Show that if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $(d_{a_n,x}-d_{b_n,x})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$, then $(d_{a_n+c_n,,x}-d_{b_n+c_n,x})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$. It may be necessary to assume that $f$ is a continuous function.

I'm not sure if that's true, but I can't convince myself that it is or isn't, so if you have a counterexample (even with a non-continuous function), I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT : if you have any hint don't hesitate neither to write it !

Comment: Bien venu à MSE. Veuillez bien écrire en anglais, s'il vous plait.

Comment: Thanks ! Your translation was very good except for one thing but I corrected it :) Have a good day !

Comment: Maybe you needed a restriction that $\epsilon\neq0$?

Comment: yes your right, thanks